MS Azure - Create new item in ADO error 400: Linking to a work item requires the full url
While configuring My Logic App in MS Azure I added a logic block to Create a new item in Azure DevOps. It works well, but I when I want to add additional relation to already existing Feature, it breaks down.
Newly created item is of a PBI type and I would like it to be a Child of an already existing feature. To do so, I added Link Type: Hierarchy-reverse and Link URL: full, pointing to the existing work item. Parameters. I provided URL in a https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_workitems/edit/{workItemId} pattern and checked it many times - it does lead to the Feature I would like to be the Parent. Still, I get the following error:
{
  "status": 400,
  "message": "Linking to a work item requires the full url.\r\nAzure DevOps ActivityId: 9ed4db68-cf41-490c-911e-841473dd90be\r\nDetails: {\"$id\":\"1\",\"innerException\":null,\"message\":\"Linking to a work item requires the full url.\",\"typeName\":\"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssPropertyValidationException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a\",\"typeKey\":\"VssPropertyValidationException\",\"errorCode\":0,\"eventId\":3000}\r\nclientRequestId: 4134e152-17d9-4cf2-9fa2-c5019d58df30",
  "error": {
    "message": "Linking to a work item requires the full url.\r\nAzure DevOps ActivityId: 9ed4db68-cf41-490c-911e-841473dd90be\r\nDetails: {\"$id\":\"1\",\"innerException\":null,\"message\":\"Linking to a work item requires the full url.\",\"typeName\":\"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssPropertyValidationException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a\",\"typeKey\":\"VssPropertyValidationException\",\"errorCode\":0,\"eventId\":3000}"
  },
  "source": "vsts-eus2.azconn-eus2-003.p.azurewebsites.net"
}

Do You have any suggestions why this URL is still after all not considered full? Any solutions suggestions?
Asking chatGPT, confirming URL points to the right resource, tested few times without Parent-Child relation adding (app works), and with it (app breaks).

The URL you need may be the one returned by the Get Work Item call (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP#get-work-item), not the one used to access within the web interface. This "other" URL is formatted https://dev.azure.com/{{org}}/_apis/wit/workItems/{{ID}}
I found this post while looking for resolution on an identical issue within Power Automate before remembering that the "API URL" is formatted differently. This worked in Power Automate and will probably work for Logic Apps.

Worked like a charm, thank You very much! :)
